# large empty space for inline-block div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two divs side by side by using inline-block. For some reason, I am seeing a large empty space at one of the divs.

I have created a pen at http://codepen.io/weima/pen/eKEbD

The problematic div is the one with class .input-area. The empty space is gone if I remove `display:inline-block` from .input-area css, but then I wont be able to put these two divs side by side.

Is there anyway to solve this without using `float`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* add `vertical-align:top` to the element in order to fix the alignment issues.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yocLF)

```
.input-area {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

The default value to the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`. If you are curious as to what this does, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278).

Comment: It would be nice to know reason why it's happening as well. +1

Comment: @Morpheus Because by default, they are aligned to *baseline*